# str_replace - doesn't work when using "< >"

Tags: php, special-characters, str-replace

I've got a problem with str_replace.

I have scraped a page with curl and now I want to replace an href id like this:
(all variables are present)

```
$search_result = str_replace("<href=\"?run=".$id."\">", "<href=\"?run=1111\">", $search_result);
```

The problem is that when I use the "<" and ">" characters in the str_replace it will not work.
Can anyone tell me why?

I also tried this (which does work like expected):

```
$test = "< something >";

$test = str_replace("<", "(", $test);

echo $test;
```

Comment: Are you sure the pattern matches anything? Do you really have `<href>` tags in whatever HTML you have (and not `<a href>`)?

Comment: it looks like all you are trying to do is replace `$id`, why would you use a string replace for that instead of setting `$id =` to your value?

Comment: I don't know what did you expect but $test == '( something >'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i'm not sure to have understand your question...

```
$test = "< something >";

$test = str_replace("<", "(", $test);
$test = str_replace(">", ")", $test);

echo $test;
```

this give me this output

```
( something )
```

so it works!

and doing a little mod to your code works fine on me, just try this:

```
$link = "<a href=\"?run=1\">hello world</a>";
$search_result = str_replace('<a href="?run=1">', "<a href=\"?run=1111\">", $link);

echo $search_result;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this regular expression to replace the multiple occurance , as < and . are escape characters we have to escape them as shown below

value.replace(/>/g, '(');

Comment: That looks like JavaScript. The question is about PHP.